# Why does Tapestry's select component not show my selected value when the option strings contain line breaks?

Tags: java, tapestry

In my application I use a `List<String>` as model for a select box. Each of the option strings contains a line break at the end.

The options are displayed fine, but it seems that Tapestry strips the line breaks before rendering the options, and then on submit it is unable to match the stripped string against the list of options, which still contains the line breaks.

For this reason my select box always comes up with the blank option selected, although the property already has a non-null value.

Comment: What type is this "field1" ? You probably need a ValueEncoder to make it work.

Comment: OK, I see my summary is too simplified to explain the real problem. Thanks for your help though! I have no found the cause of my problem: My options was a `List<String>` and each `String` had a linebreak at the end. It seems that Tapestry strips the linebreaks before rendering the `<option>` tags and then on submit it cannot match the stripped options against the non-stripped ones on the server side. So always strip linebreaks before adding your options to a select box!

Comment: I don't think browsers support linebreaks in option elements

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided a `model` parameter so tapestry has no way of knowing the available values. The model must be a `SelectModel` instance. There's a few options for creating a `SelectModel`.

1. Provide a comma separated String and let tapestry's TypeCoercer create an appropriate SelectModel.
2. Provide a java.util.List and let tapestry's TypeCoercer create an appropriate SelectModel.
3. Provide a java.util.Map and let tapestry's TypeCoercer create an appropriate SelectModel.
4. @Inject [SelectModelFactory](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3.7/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/SelectModelFactory.html) and invoke `create(List<?> objects, String labelProperty)` to create a SelectModel from a List using a bean property as the label for each.
5. Create a custom `SelectModel` yourself.

http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3.7/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Select.html
http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3.7/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/SelectModel.html
http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3.7/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/SelectModelFactory.html
http://tapestry.apache.org/typecoercer-service.html

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually I have a model parameter, I just omitted it from my example code to keep the example small, which I shouldn't have. See my comment above for what the real problem was.